# What are the dimensions of LIGO Detector evacuated chambers?

Tags: black-hole, space-time, gravitational-waves, instruments

The LIGO complex is very large, but I assume that there is a very small chamber that actually does the science since they are measuring very small sheers. How big around is the actual evacuated chamber?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The arms are $4\,\mathrm{km}\,\times\, 1.2\,\mathrm{m}$:

From the [LIGO webpage](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/vacuum):

> The 1.2 m diameter beam tubes were created in 19-20 m-long segments, rolled into a tube with a continuous spiral weld. While a mathematically perfect cylinder will not collapse under pressure, any small imperfection in a real tube would allow it to buckle (a crushed vacuum tube would be catastrophic). To prevent collapse, LIGO's tubes are supported with stiffener rings that provide a significant layer of resistance to buckling under the extreme pressure of the atmosphere. The tubes must withstand these stresses for at least 20 years.

Answer (score 2):

LIGO detectors have two 4 km arms, and everything in those arms in suspended in a vacuum. The actual dimensions of those arms I was unable to find, but [the published paper here](https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102) has more information for you to peruse.